# How to access form object parameters in active admin

Tags: ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

I hope this is actually possible but I can't seem to access my forms parameters to send with my custom action.

My aim here is for a user to fill in their form, click on a Preview button that will show them what their post will look like, I have created the view which is fine, just passing the parameters is an issue.

This is my current form

```
# Create Blog Post
form do |f|
  inputs 'Blog' do
    f.semantic_errors
    f.input :title
    f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: Category.all
    f.input :comments, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, cols: 10 }
    f.input :published, as: :boolean
  end
  inputs 'Submit' do
    f.actions do
    f.action :submit
    f.action :cancel
    f.action :reset
    li do
      link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(post: { title: "test", comments: 'comments', category_id: '1' }) # Hardcoded for now
    end
   end
 end
end

# Collection Action to handle object
collection_action :preview, method: :get do
  @post = Post.new(permitted_params[:post])
end
```

So with everything the way it is (hardcoded) the params are passed through and output in my preview view, but as soon as I try accessing the forms object/params nothing gets passed through:

```
# Console Output
1 - link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(post: { title: f.object.title, comments: f.object.comments, category_id: f.object.category_id})
#<Post:0x007f8bbe1fc4c0 id: nil, title: "", comments: "", category_id: nil, slug: nil, published: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2 - link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(post: { title: f.title, comments: f.comments, category_id: f.category_id })
# Console Output
#<Post:0x007f8bbe1fc4c0 id: nil, title: nil, comments: nil, category_id: nil, slug: nil, published: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
3 - link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(@post)
# Console Output
#<Post:0x007f8bbe1fc4c0 id: nil, title: nil, comments: nil, category_id: nil, slug: nil, published: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Not sure where else to go with this, `f.object.param` seems close but passing through empty strings?

What alternative solutions could I consider?

### Update

When outputting params to the console I get this returned

```
{"action"=>"preview", "controller"=>"my_admin_panel/posts"}
```

Comment: That means when you tried to output `params` in your `collection_action :preview` it's blank? Can show the console log for this action?

Comment: @nayiaw updated with console outputs

Comment: more interested to see the `params` instead of `@post`..

Comment: @nayiaw params updated in question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a post? When you load this page the fields do not have any value thus the link will not load any parameter(you can inspect element on the preview link and see that the link does not have any parameter).

One way is to use JavaScript to catch the value before the link has routed in controller.

Comment: Within my preview action I am doing '@post = Post.new(permited_params[:post])' to have a new instance of @post available but not saved

Comment: I mean when you load this form you do not have any data that's why your `@post` is nil all the time. Rails don't know what's entered inside your form unless it's a form submit button, `link_to` won't catch your form data.

Comment: @Richlewis - the params don't ever make it there? - Not sure how you managed to get it to work?